# Solr indexing ñ

Tags: solr

I need to index words in Spanish and have test with ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory. This filter works great for accented characters (converts á -> a) but also converts ñ -> n and this is not a valid behaviour (give wrong results with some words).

Is there a way to exclude a letter from ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory or another filter to try?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MappingCharFilter and customise the mappings that are in mapping-FoldToASCII.txt

```
<charFilter class="solr.MappingCharFilterFactory"
 mapping="/solr/trunk/solr/example/solr/conf/mapping-FoldToASCII.txt"/>
```

(change location file to location on your system)

Comment: I have reached the same conclusion. I have done a sample test and I think is the best solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `extending BaseTokenFilterFactory` and in the schema.xml file point to it as one of your index/search filter